# WPF подключение к базе данных Access

Tags: wpf, база-данных, access, oledb

Программа на данный момент подключается к бд через Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 работает только с установленным microsoft database engine.
Есть ли возможность сделать так чтоб программа работал без установки этого ядра?

Строка подключения:

Код взаимодействия с бд:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\DESKTOP-18KKC11\Server\DataBase.accdb

```
    public class MobileContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Action> ActionsAll { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ButtonGen> ButtonGen { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Question { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subdivision> Subdivision { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Library> Library { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exercises> Exercises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StateTest> StateTest { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Normativ> Normativ { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {

         optionsBuilder.UseJet(Properties.Settings.Default.BDConnection);
        // optionsBuilder.UseJet(Properties.Settings.Default.BDTest);

    }

}
```

Comment: А что за БД вы используете? MS Sql или что-то еще. Если да, то не получится. Если хотите чтобы в программе была именно бд - посмотрите на `SQLite`, файл БД может создаваться в любом месте (если разрешено пользователем), это очень легковесная база данных, но нужно понимать, что она не может заменить полноценные гиганты типа MS SQL и ему подобные, однако в своей практике, особенно в wpf, я бы не стал обращаться внимания на это. Эта БД вполне себе способна на все при правильном использовании. Если не обязательно наличие БД - всегда есть файлы - json/xml и тд.

Comment: БД Access, на данный момент пытаюсь прейти на net.cor и попробовать там.